# Polygon Nodes do not have separate coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates

I'm attempting to measure the distance of a series of points from a smaller number of polygons. As a first step, I've changed the polygons into points along their border, via the

```
Vector> Geometry Tools> Extract Nodes
```

command. This gives me the following result, after I've manually deleted irrelevant borders.

[image]

It's now my intention to export these points' coordinates into R to do some rudimentary neighbor and distance calculations. But when I open the attribute table, all the points representing the borders of the separate regions share a single geographic coordinate (which appears to approximate the polygon's centroid, but that's a guess). It's like the following:

[image: Image2]

Is there a different way to convert a polygon's borders to points, and recover the points' coordinates themselves?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Coordinates in the attribute table do not get updated automatically when the geometry of the feature changes. You need to update them manually:

- Enable editing of the points layer
- Open the attribute table
- Open the field calculator
- Update the INTPTLON and INTPTLAT fields using the expressions "$x"
  and "$y" respectively (they're in the Geometry group).

You may also be interested in the 'Hub Distance' tool in the mmqgis plugin: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Comment: brilliant, this worked perfectly. thanks!

I had separately looked at the Hub Distance command, but (to my superficial understanding) it looked as if that measures distance between a point and a polygon's centroid, where I need the distance between a polygon and the closest border of  a polygon. Is my understanding of this function faulty?